# Rounded bottomnavigation view , How to achieve the effect from this image (including item glow)?

Tags: java, xml, bottomnavigationview

I have been trying to achieve the look of this bottom nav, rounded and slightly 3d pop out look. With the white glow on the clicked item.  I am using this currently. however the output is not that great. Can anyone assist in making it happen? Only XML codes.

```
<!-- custom_bottom_nav_background.xml -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Top Rounded Shape -->
    <item android:top="10dp" android:right="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/gray" /> <!-- Background color -->
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp" android:topRightRadius="20dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[BottomNav Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4QpU.jpg)

I have tried creating a custom XML for rounded bottom_nav and putting it in the cardview but none of those things have even close by effect to this image.